# Obtaining the Drag-and-drop rank through the API

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm trying to get the drag and drop rank through the api in an app (using sdk 1.32).

The query fields I fetch for `HierarchicalRequirement` include the `DragAndDrop` field, but the response includes the `Rank` field instead, which is a numeric field (as opposed to the `DragAndDrop` field which I can see in the API playground, which is a cryptic alphanumeric field).

The problem is that the `Rank` field which is returned does not reflect the order of stories as they are displayed in Rally.

Any suggestion on how to get the `DragAndDrop` field in the response?

Our workspace is configured for Drag-and-drop sorting (not manual)

Answer (score 0):

In v2.0 of WS API there is alpha-numeric string `DragAndDropRank`, but no decimal `Rank`. Notice version=v2.0 in the URL below:

[image]

In deprecated versions of WS API prior to v2.0, including the one you are using, there is decimal `Rank`, but no alpha-numeric string `DragAndDropRank`. Notice version=1.32 in the URL below:

[image]

When using 1.32 `DragAndDropRank` cannot be fetched.To get `DragAndDropRank` you need to use v2.0.

However, the deprecation of decimal `Rank` attribute and introduction of alpha-numeric `DragAndDropRank` did not affect the ranking of the existing artifacts due to implementation of an internal mechanism that translated decimal `Rank` to alphanumeric string. You may see a KnowledgeBase article ["How to interpret DragAndDropRank"](https://rallydev.force.com/answers?id=kA0a0000000YcYQ) for a rough approximation of this mechanism.

In any case, the old `Rank` still has to reflect the relative ranking of stories. There may be other factors that affect what is displayed and in what order because in the UI it depends on project scoping,order ,sorting(what field a grid is being sorted on in Rally) and the type of page(e.g. Backlog page displays it differently from User Stories summary page).

Comment: Here is an updated link: 
https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/47752/rally-interpret-draganddroprank.html

Answer (score 0):

As nickm mentioned, the "DragAndDropRank" field in "HeirarchicalRequirement" does have an alphanumeric string. But when I tried to sort by that alphanumeric string (multiple stories across multiple features) it didn't give an appropriate rank sorted view of stories. (Version 2.0)

I had to use "order=Rank" to get the appropriate sorted views when querying for stories which is what you seem to be trying to do:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?projectScopeUp=false&workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/{WORKSPACE ID}&project=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/{PROJECT ID}&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=100&order=Rank
```

(see https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)